# Use the definition of a limit to show that $\lim_{z \to z_0} (az + b) = az_0 + b.$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Let $a,b, z_0$ denote complex constants. Use the definition of a limit to show that 
>   $$\lim_{z \to z_0} (az + b) = az_0 + b.$$

Here is what I have done:

\begin{align*}
|az + b - (az_0 + b)| &= |az - az_0 + b - b|\\
&= |a(z - z_0)|\\
&= |a||z - z_0|.
\end{align*}

So for a positive number $\epsilon$,

$$|az + b - (az_0 + b)| < \epsilon \text{ whenever } |a||z - z_0| < \epsilon$$

or in other words $|az + b - (az_0 + b)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|z - z_0| < \delta$ where $\delta = \epsilon/|a|$.

Have I proved the statement correctly?

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: Perfect, excepting one small possible issue you need to avoid in the end... You divide by $|a|$, and what happens if $|a|=0$?

Comment: It looks like a textbook example of a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof to me, other than the point raised by N.S.

Comment: So I just make a note of that in my proof?.. where d - e/|a|, |a| != 0

Comment: You can either split the end in two cases: case 1 $|a| \neq 0$, case 2: $|a|=0$, or, pretty standard trick, observe that $|a||z - z_0| < \epsilon$ happens when $|z-z_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{|a|+1}$.

Comment: Just write "if $a=0$ then there is nothing to prove, so let us assume $a\neq 0$", I think that will be ok with most mathematicians

Comment: This looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your proof works for $a \neq 0$. You can deal with the case where $a = 0$ separately or choose $\epsilon$ in such a way that the proof works for all $a$ (see N.S.'s comment for example). Aside from this your proof is correct.